# How to sort each individual string in a list of strings?

Tags: python, string, list, sorting

I want to sort each string in a list of string to be in alphabetical order.

For example,

```
l1 = ["bba", "yxx", "abc"]
```

I want to sort it to be

```
l1 = ["abb", "xxy", "abc"]
```

I can do it in a for loop but wonder if this is a more pythonic way using python list comprehension. Thanks :D

Comment: `["".join(sorted(i)) for i in l1]`

Answer (score 4):

Using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
>>> l1 = ["bba", "yxx", "abc"]
>>> [''.join(sorted(s)) for s in l1]
['abb', 'xxy', 'abc']
```

Answer (score 2):

by List compression with sorted method and string join method

```
>>> l1 = ["bba", "yxx", "abc"]
>>> [''.join(sorted(i)) for i in l1]
['abb', 'xxy', 'abc']
>>>
```

---

by lambda

```
>>> l1
['bba', 'yxx', 'abc']
>>> map(lambda x:"".join(sorted(x)),l1)
['abb', 'xxy', 'abc']
```

---

For Python beginner

1. Iterate every item of list `l1` by `for` loop.
2. Use sorted() method to sort item and return list.
3. Use `join()` method to create string from the list.
4. Use `append()` list method to add sored item to new list `l2`.
5. print l2

e.g.

```
>>> l1
['bba', 'yxx', 'abc']
>>> l2 = []
>>> for i in l1:
...    a = sorted(i)
...    b = "".join(a)
...    l2.append(b)
... 
>>> l2
['abb', 'xxy', 'abc']
```

Comment: the lambda one needs to be converted in to a list if we want to be fair and compare times.

Answer (score -1):

Just use the `sorted` built-in function.

```
l1 = ["bba", "yxx", "abc"]
print [''.join(sorted(i)) for i in l1]
```

Another way of using list comprehensions (if your strings have a fixed length of 3) would be:

```
print ['{0}{1}{2}'.format(*sorted(i)) for i in l1]
```